# How Do I calculate percentage on array field using mongodb aggregation?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have following documents

```
users = [
  {
    type: 'A',
    name: 'anil',
    logins: [
      { at: '2-3-2019', device: 'mobile' },
      { at: '3-3-2019', device: 'desktop' },
      { at: '4-3-2019', device: 'tab' },
      { at: '5-3-2019', device: 'mobile' }
    ]
  },
  {
    type: 'A',
    name: 'rakesh',
    logins: [
      { at: '2-3-2019', device: 'desktop' },
      { at: '3-3-2019', device: 'mobile' },
      { at: '4-3-2019', device: 'desktop' },
      { at: '5-3-2019', device: 'tab' }
    ]
  },
  {
    type: 'A',
    name: 'rahul',
    logins: [
      { at: '2-3-2019' device: 'tab' },
      { at: '3-3-2019' device: 'mobile' },
      { at: '4-3-2019' device: 'tab' },
      { at: '5-3-2019' device: 'tab' }
    ]
  }
]
```

I need to calculate percentage of device used by each user which of type "A".

if we look at user **anil** the device usage is,

```
mobile: 50%
desktop: 25%
tab: 25%
```

the highest usage is mobile device with **50%** usage, So it should consider as **mobile** device.
Like above the final output would be,

```
[
  {
    name: 'anil',
    device: 'mobile',
    logins: 50%
  },
  {
    name: 'rakesh',
    device: 'desktop',
    logins: 50%
  },
  {
    name: 'rahul',
    device: 'tab',
    logins: 75%
  }
]
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This can be achieved using the javascript `.reduce` method, but since you want mongo to do the processing, take a look at `https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/#map-reduce` method from mongo docs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

Here overall logic is to find the duplicates inside the array, after that  you just need to do is [**`$map`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) over the `logins` array to calculate the percentage of the device using the formula

```
(numberOfDevices * 100) / total size of the array
```

It will be better if you just remove one by one stage from the below aggregation to understand it.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "type": "A" }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "logins": {
      "$arrayToObject": {
        "$map": {
          "input": { "$setUnion": ["$logins.device"] },
          "as": "m",
          "in": {
            "k": "$$m",
            "v": {
              "$divide": [
                {
                  "$multiply": [
                    { "$size": {
                      "$filter": {
                        "input": "$logins",
                        "as": "d",
                        "cond": {
                          "$eq": ["$$d.device", "$$m"]
                        }
                      }
                    }},
                    100
                  ]
                },
                { "$size": "$logins" }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1EopJQO5yNA)

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "logins": {
      "desktop": 25,
      "mobile": 50,
      "tab": 25
    },
    "name": "anil",
    "type": "A"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "logins": {
      "desktop": 50,
      "mobile": 25,
      "tab": 25
    },
    "name": "rakesh",
    "type": "A"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
    "logins": {
      "mobile": 25,
      "tab": 75
    },
    "name": "rahul",
    "type": "A"
  }
]
```

**Exact output**-> Here I have just find the [**`$max`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) element from the array of object after getting the percentage of all devices.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "type": "A" }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "logins": {
      "$map": {
        "input": { "$setUnion": ["$logins.device"] },
        "as": "m",
        "in": {
          "k": "$$m",
          "v": {
            "$divide": [
              {
                "$multiply": [
                  { "$size": {
                    "$filter": {
                      "input": "$logins",
                      "as": "d",
                      "cond": {
                        "$eq": ["$$d.device", "$$m"]
                      }
                    }
                  }},
                  100
                ]
              },
              { "$size": "$logins" }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": {
      "$mergeObjects": [
        "$$ROOT",
        {
          "$arrayElemAt": [
            "$logins",
            {
              "$indexOfArray": [
                "$logins.v",
                { "$max": "$logins.v" }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }},
  { "$project": { "logins": 0 }}
])
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2_EGoeTOoR8)

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "k": "mobile",
    "name": "anil",
    "type": "A",
    "v": 50
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "k": "desktop",
    "name": "rakesh",
    "type": "A",
    "v": 50
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
    "k": "tab",
    "name": "rahul",
    "type": "A",
    "v": 75
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks @Ashh this works exactly the same as expected output.